# How to Run CakePHP 3 Shell in Cpanel

Tags: shell, cron, cakephp-3.0

Very simple and straightforward question. Yes I've searched and searched, but couldn't find an answer on the internet that works with CakePHP 3. I'm trying to run a CakePHP 3 shell as cron job on cpanel. Can anyone help out please?

Comment: Can you run the shell task from the command line? If so, you should be able to simply put the same command line (perhaps with a full path instead of relative) into the cron setup. What have you tried, and what errors do you get from those attempts?

Comment: Show us the line you put in cron. If what you start is a script, show us the script. Try running the shell with a reduced environemnt, i.e. `env -i /full/path/to/program`. If that doesn't work, there's your answer: missing environment variables.